# Identify the systemd unit file from process name

Tags: linux, systemd

For some service unit files, the unit file name does not correspond to the name of the daemon.

For example Postfix: The unit file is called `postfix.service` but the underlying daemons launched are named `master` (main daemon) and `qmgr` and `tlsmgr` (helper daemons).

I am looking for a way to get the unit name based on any of the daemon names.

Using `systemctl status postfix` (as an example), I can see that it shows the processes it has spawned.

Using `systemctl --all status` I can get everything .... but just a plain grep into that mess is not going to get the unit name back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *libsystemd* API function is `sd_pid_get_unit(…)`.  From the command line, you can use `ps` with the UNIT column (if it was compiled with libsystemd support):

```
$ ps -e -o pid,unit,cmd
    PID UNIT                            CMD
      1 init.scope                      /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
    315 postfix.service                 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
   3057 cronie.service                  /usr/bin/CROND -n
   3107 galed.service                   /usr/bin/galed
   3182 getty@tty1.service              /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
  29171 postfix.service                 /usr/lib/postfix/bin/master -w
  32758 postfix.service                 qmgr -l -t unix -u

$ ps -o unit= 32758
postfix.service

$ ps -o unit= -C tlsmgr
postfix.service

$ systemctl status $(pidof pickup)
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-03-27 17:24:24 EEST; 2 weeks 2 days ago
 Main PID: 29171 (master)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─  315 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─ 8720 pickup -l -t unix -u
           ├─29171 /usr/lib/postfix/bin/master -w
           └─32758 qmgr -l -t unix -u

$ grep :name=systemd: /proc/$(pidof pickup)/cgroup
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/postfix.service
# do not rely on this one, as the cgroup structure will change in the coming months
```

Comment: ps -o unit= -C tlsmgr was exactly what i was looking for. I was aware of  systemctl status $(pidof pickup) but that output is almost impossible to parse to get the unit name (postfix.service). Thanks!